# How to validate only the JSON signature(Not Values) returned by Micro Service using Spring Cloud Contract

Tags: spring-cloud-contract

I have a groovy script where i am trying to validate the JSON attributes in a method in the base test class(assertDepartment).

```
import org.springframework.cloud.contract.spec.Contract

Contract.make {

    request {
        method 'GET'
        url '/dept-service/12345'
    }

    response {
        status 200
        headers {
            header 'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
        }
        body ($(consumer('dept.json'), producer(execute('assertDepartment($it)'))))
    }
}
```

**dept.json**

```
[{

    "departmentList": [
         {
            "dept_code": "12345",
            "dept_name": "AAA",
            "desc": "aaa",
         },
         {
            "dept_code": "12345",
            "dept_name": "BBB",
            "desc": "bbb",
         }
     ]
}]
```

From the Publisher point of view, it is all good, but the stubs are  including the JSON with values as is, per the dept.json above.

From the Consumer point of view, i would like to verify only the signature of the JSON, but not by values, as i am connecting to a different database.
Here the JSON comparison is STRICT with respect to values.
How can i send the generic JSON format to Consumer and how can i restrict only attribute checking(like dept_code, dept_name, desc ) not the values (AAA, aaa, BBB, bbb)

Please help.

Answer (score -1):

After going through the documentation, i have realized the below with respect to Spring Cloud Contract implementation.
- Spring Cloud Contract Request/Responses are Static, Not Dynamic
  We have to have specific static request/response data for each case/scenario
  Producer can not switch it to real time, and can not dynamically change the input and expect the Consumer to have the same output

- Spring Cloud Contract Producer JSON Responses are Static as the Consumer is going to compare with the same forever
  If Producer is going to provide a JSON Response based on an Account with multiple possible combination of datasets, then the Consumer also should invoke the Service via the Stubs with the same Account input, otherwise it is going to Fail
  Consumer is not going to Connect to any Database, but just compares the JSON in the Stubs against the Hard-coded response at Consumer end.

### Nice to Have

Producer/Consumer should be able to Connect to either same or different databases and switch the Request input dynamically, which makes the Integration Testing using Spring Cloud Contract More Robust.

Case: 
Consider a Bank Account with Joint Account Holder information.
Producer exposes a Micro Service which gives Account information to the Consumer.
Today, Mr. Bob has an Account without any Joint Account holder information.
Producer generates the Stubs and communicates the same with 10 Consumers.
Tomorrow, Mr. Bob wants to Add his spouse Ms. Lily as a Joint Account Holder.
Now, Producer generates the Stubs and communicates the same with 10 Consumers.
Out of which 3 Consumers do not need Joint Account information, but 7 of them are strictly dependent on the complete information.

Firstly, All the 10 Consumers will have to re-write the Test cases from their end, as the Integration Test is going to Fail, because it returns an Additional information but as the Consumers are statically comparing the response with the hard-coded value/signature.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1773866/marcin-grzejszczak
Marcin Grzejszczak, Can you please review my answer and correct me if i am wrong. Thanks

Comment: The tests will not fail when you have an unexpected field. You should always ignore the unnecessary fields. The consumers will get a field that they don't care about